# Is it possible to edit an iOS app binary/localization without a Mac?

Tags: ios, macos

The company I work for has a mobile app that was developed some time ago and we need to change all versions of the app to reflect our new office address.
The problem is that for the iOS version of the app we no longer have a Mac so cannot use XCode to recompile it.
The strings are all kept in Localizable.strings files (for English and two other languages) so we are wondering if there is a simple way we can update just this without having to buy or borrow a computer?

Comment: Is this app available in the appstore? I mean, do these changes need to appear on user's devices?

Comment: Yes, it appears to have been last edited just under a year ago. I think my boss would like the users to have an automatic update to the app or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to recompile the app and increase the version number if you want users to get an update notification. There's no way to upload another binary to the AppStore